# What does it mean to infect people with silent java drive?

Tags: php, web-development, javascript, security, java

I've got a weird contact message through my website, claiming they have found a security vulnerability and wonder if I have a bug bounty program.

The details they shared:

```
Only what I can say is that I found a way to infect people with silent java drive by on one of your websites .
```

What does this mean to infect people with silent java drive?

Answer (score 2):

It's called a "drive by" or "drive by download". From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drive-by_download):

> Drive-by download means two things, each concerning the unintended
>   download of computer software from the Internet:
>
> 1. Downloads which a person authorized but without understanding the consequences (e.g. 2. downloads which install an unknown or
>      counterfeit executable program, ActiveX component, or Java applet).
>
> Any download that happens without a person's knowledge, often a
>   computer virus, spyware, malware, or crimeware.
>
> Drive-by downloads may happen when visiting a website, viewing an
>   e-mail message or by clicking on a deceptive pop-up window:[2] by
>   clicking on the window in the mistaken belief that, for instance, an
>   error report from the computer' operating system itself is being
>   acknowledged, or that an innocuous advertisement pop-up is being
>   dismissed. In such cases, the "supplier" may claim that the user
>   "consented" to the download, although actually the user was unaware of
>   having started an unwanted or malicious software download. Websites
>   that exploit the Windows Metafile vulnerability (eliminated by a
>   Windows update of 5 January 2006) may provide examples of drive-by
>   downloads of this sort.
>
> Hackers use different techniques to obfuscate the malicious code, so
>   that antivirus software is unable to recognize it. The code is
>   executed in hidden iframes, and can go undetected.
>
> A drive-by install (or installation) is a similar event. It refers to
>   installation rather than download (though sometimes the two terms are
>   used interchangeably).

Basically they claim to have found a vulnerability in your website where they can force users to download and execute code to infect their computers. This is probably due to a XSS flaw in your website.

Comment: Sounds like someone trying to sell website security services...you can scan your website for exploits with various online services - many for [free](https://www.google.com/search?q=website+security+scanner&oq=website+security+scanner&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l4j0.3228j0&sourceid=chrome&espvd=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#es_sm=93&q=website+security+scanner+free).

Comment: @dan did u ever use a specific one from that google search list?

Comment: @Noam I modified and compiled my own using [skipfish](https://code.google.com/p/skipfish/) which is open-source. I try to avoid recommending commercial products & services, but there's a recent question [here](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/53225/host-header-vulnerability-reported-by-acunetix-scanner) regarding one where the author cited in that had responded here...